# C# Serialize xml sub element with type defined in attribut

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, system.xml

I would like to serialize with **System.Xml.Serialization** the following XML code. Is there a way to have it inside an object containing the type (**typeRef**) of this variable (**text**) defined at runtime ?

```
<input>    
 <inputExpression typeRef="integer">
   <text>4</text>
 </inputExpression>
</input>
```

*typeref can only be primitives types*

I would expect to use the implementation of **IXmlSerializable** on an "InputExpression" class but I'm blocked at this point.

Comment: It sounds like you want to deserialize the xml into a object. Is that right? If so, can you share the class definition of the class you are trying to deserialize to?

Comment: Yep exactly, but the class is not defined yet. This class needs to have a property with a type defined at runtime, that is my issue.